# How to get full image url from Custom option with image uploaded from frontend in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Custom option with image

I'm new in magento 2. I'm trying to fetch custom options uploaded image.

I have created image upload from customizable options.
Here is object that i have printed. I wanted to full image url.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [title] => sample_image.jpg
    [quote_path] => custom_options/quote/s/a/aKuwRrgMN9Mku3J9QkI5aJfJN9i3p9q4
    [order_path] => custom_options/order/s/a/aKuwRrgMN9Mku3J9QkI5aJfJN9i3p9q4
    [fullpath] => /xampp/htdocs/pub/media/custom_options/quote/s/a/aKuwRrgMN9Mku3J9QkI5aJfJN9i3p9q4
    [size] => 8462
    [width] => 275
    [height] => 183
    [secret_key] => f41cc17e392062a9c669
    [url] => stdClass Object
        (
            [route] => sales/download/downloadCustomOption
            [params] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2298
                    [key] => f41cc17e392062a9c669
                )

        )

)
```

How can we get 'sample_image.jpg' full path?
anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below way.

```
/**
 * Get image URL
 *
 * @return bool|string
 * @throws LocalizedException
 */
public function getImageUrl()
{
    $url = false;
    $image = $this->getImage();
    if ($image) {
        if (is_string($image)) {
            $uploader = $this->uploaderPool->getUploader('image');
            $url = $uploader->getBaseUrl().$uploader->getBasePath().$image;
        } else {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('Something went wrong while getting the image url.')
            );
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Chirag,
Thanks for response. 
I tried your code but but i'm new in magento 2 and don't know how to use '$this->uploaderPool'. For your information i have created my custom module and trying to fetch image path from order_items. So can you please suggest how i can use $this->uploaderPool? code reference will be good. Thanks